# Installation OpenLDAP on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap, centos7

I'm f**ollowing this OpenLDAP step by step tutorial**: http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=openldap&f=1 *Important: I'm working on CentOS 7*

But when in the first part I try to start `slapd` with: `systemctl start slapd`, it throws me an **error** that I can't solve.

I looked for in web, StackOverflow and Server Fault but anyone has the same problem.

This is the **error**:

```
# systemctl start slapd
Job for slapd.service failed. See 'systemctl status slapd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

And here the **stack trace** or error when I check the `systemctl status`.

```
 [root@localhost openldap]# systemctl status slapd -l
    slapd.service - OpenLDAP Server Daemon
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slapd.service; disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since dv 2015-01-09 12:03:41 CET; 3min 9s ago
      Process: 5507 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h ${SLAPD_URLS} $SLAPD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      Process: 5492 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/openldap/check-config.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

    gen 09 12:03:41 localhost.localdomain runuser[5495]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
    gen 09 12:03:41 localhost.localdomain check-config.sh[5492]: Checking configuration file failed:
    gen 09 12:03:41 localhost.localdomain check-config.sh[5492]: 54afb58d ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif"
    gen 09 12:03:41 localhost.localdomain check-config.sh[5492]: 54afb58d unable to open file "/openldap/slapd.pid": 2 (No such file or directory)
    gen 09 12:03:41 localhost.localdomain slapcat[5500]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
    gen 09 12:03:41 localhost.localdomain slapd[5507]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.39 (Jun  9 2014 23:23:12) $
                                                               mockbuild@worker1.bsys.centos.org:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.39/openldap-2.4.39/servers/slapd
    gen 09 12:03:41 localhost.localdomain slapd[5509]: DIGEST-MD5 common mech free
    gen 09 12:03:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: slapd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
    gen 09 12:03:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon.
    gen 09 12:03:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit slapd.service entered failed state.
```

My question is: How can I do? Is there any solution? Or what is the guideline to follow for fix the problem?

How I can start to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [CentOS OpenLDAP help page](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-ldap-quickstart.html). It is very concise and no fluff. Prior to doing so - please revert all the config files to their original state. Can be confirmed via:

```
# rpm -V openldap-server
```

If above command shows any files modified - either remove and reinstall openldap-server or fetch files over from backup.

Answer (score 1):

I also used that guide to set up OpenLDAP on CentOS 7. Once I only installed `openldap-servers` without the client and it completely failed; there were permissions issues and slapd failed to start, etc. I agree with others about starting over and following the directions exactly.

But even so, there are some issues in the guide that are helpful to have documented:

- If you copy-paste from the guide into the ldif files, be sure to fix any wrapped lines, they caused errors for me (`chdomain.ldif` in particular).
- In `basedomain.ldif`, `o: Server World` and `dc: Server` should be changed to the correct domain, otherwise you get this error:

  > ldap_add: Naming violation (64)
  >       additional info: value of single-valued naming attribute 'dc' conflicts with value present in entry
- The final `ldapadd` command should also be changed to the correct domain or else you will get invalid credentials errors.

Those errors really weren't intuitive, but I was able to complete the guide and configure OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 0):

You have some kind of error in your configuration files. At the very least, you made an error when creating your initial config file and likely changed what's stated in the tutorial:

The tutorial states:

```
 pidfile     /run/openldap/slapd.pid
```

but OpenLDAP tries to create `/openldap/slapd.pid`, which can't work as `/openldap` won't exist as a directory.

Start over from scratch.

Comment: I can't finish any LDAP tutorial. T.T Do you know any tutorial for very beginners? Please, help me.